# Why do people keep saying Hillary Clinton is in the woods?

Tags: united-states, hillary-clinton

I keep seeing references to Hillary Clinton being in the woods of Wisconsin... can someone explain what's actually going on there? Is it just that she's living at home in Wisconsin, and not accepting visitors from the media?

Comment: Some sources would help. Did you do any research before you asked?

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/woods. Someone, please flag this for migration to ELL?

Comment: This isn't a figurative use and should not go to ELL.

Comment: Heard drunk, wine-soaked, and bitter. But in the woods?  What does that even mean?

Comment: @Brythan - I'm not sure how Wisconsin would figure in any literal use. But I'm not on social media and typically a year or two late to meme parties, so i'll bow to your wisdom.

Comment: It's also considered a joke, even Hillary herself mentioned it during a Senate event

Answer (score 5):

Hillary Clinton lives in New York, not Wisconsin.

After the election, she was walking her dogs and someone [took a selfie](http://mashable.com/2016/11/10/hillary-clinton-hiking-photo/) with her.  This was widely covered on television news at the time.  Apparently it has happened [again](https://www.buzzfeed.com/hattiesoykan/people-think-hillary-clinton-is-lost-in-the-woods).

It's possible that you're seeing references to people making jokes relating this event to other events.  This would be clearer if we had an example of where you're seeing it.  An example that I found:  [Hillary Clinton Emerges From the Woods to Honor Katy Perry](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2016/11/30/hillary_clinton_emerges_from_the_woods_to_honor_katy_perry.html).

There may be similar jokes trying to connect the recount in Wisconsin to her hiking selfies.

Comment: From the context where I have heard the references, I was under the impression that those comments did use the wood encounter anecdota to comment/joke about her low public profile since election day  (as in "she is not giving interviews because she is out of reach from civilization"). This may be just my interpretation (and, in any case, it is usually understood that jokes are subject to exaggeration and other comic resources and should not be accepted as 100% accurate).